# Memory map classpath resource

Tags: java

For the static resources being served from my server (which are embedded in the JAR) - I'd like to memory map them.

I wrote the following:

```
    try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(classpathItem)) {
        byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);

        ByteBuffer directBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
        directBuffer.put(bytes);
        directBuffer.flip();

        return directBuffer;
    }
```

Then I figured, there must be an option in Java to do this already (perhaps a JVM argument). Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late, but I just stumbled across the question.

The short answer is no, you can't memory map resources from your jar.
This is due to how resources are stored in the jar itself. A jar file is really just a zip file, and resources are contents of the zip file. This is the reason that you can't get a `File`, or anything besides a `URL` or an `InputStream` to resources inside the jar. The `URL` just lets you open an `InputStream` and the `InputStream` itself just lets you stream the contents of the resource, unzipping them as it goes.

Interestingly though, this would be possible if the `ZipFileSystem` supported memory mapping.

Here is a snippet that *would* work if `ZipFileSystem` supported memory mapping:

```
// Hack to get URL to running jar
String path = Main.class.getResource("Main.class").toString().split("!")[0];
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create(path), 
        Collections.singletonMap("create", "true"));
Path p = fs.getPath("/path/to/my/resource");
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(p);
MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
```

Problem is you get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem$4.map(ZipFileSystem.java:799)
        at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

It's probably for the best that you can't do this since you'd most likely get terrible performance anyways. Zip files layout the files flat and compressed, so there is no easy way to lay them out without first allocating a memory mapped buffer for yourself, and unzipping the contents into it.

Probably too late to help you, but it might stop someone from going on a wild goose chase later :P

Answer (score 0):

You may create war with static content.

Dirs:

```
war
  WebContent
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
      classes
      web.xml
    index.html 
    ... etc static contents
  build.xml
```

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**build.xml**

```
<target name="war" description="Bundles the application as a WAR file" >
    <mkdir dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="WebContent">
                <fileset dir="../dist">
                    <include name="**/*.html"/>
                    <include name="**/*.js"/>
                    <include name="**/*.css"/>
                    <include name="*.html"/>
                    <include name="*.js"/>
                    <include name="*.css"/>
                    <include name="**/**/*.png"/>
                </fileset>
    </copy>

    <war destfile="ScadaLTS.war"
                    basedir="WebContent"
                    needxmlfile="false">
    </war>
</target>
```

command to build: **ant war**

To serve static content may simple war than create jar.

Comment: I'm a tad confused, how does this answer my question?

Comment: This simple solution serves static content (resource) on own server tomcat.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the question I was asking. Put simply, I am asking, "How do you memory map a classpath resource?"

Comment: It is DRY. May see to tomcat how is serve static content resource but is repeat code.